# How to detect if a user is signed in to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

How would I detect *specifically* if a user is signed into iCloud?  Checking the return value of URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier is very limited:

1) It can't distinguish between a user not being signed into iCloud versus other scenarios, e.g. iCloud not enabled.
2) It doesn't appear to change its behavior if a user signs into iCloud from the Settings app while the game is still running in the background, then returns to the app to try to access iCloud services.

Is there a more reliable way to detect specifically if a user is signed in?

Answer (score 5):

Also, from iOS 6 on there is the method `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken]`, which tells you if iCloud is available and also if the user has switched accounts

Comment: interestingly `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken]` works on my iPhone but returns nil always on my iPad

Comment: Note that `ubiquityIdentityToken` is `nil` if you are logged into iCloud and the app is not using documents (e.g. key-value-store only).

Comment: on iOS 9.3+ ubiquityIdentityToken works on iPad as well

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to distinguish "user is not logged in" from "iCloud is not enabled". What you get to know in your app is whether your app currently has access to iCloud, but if the answer is no then you don't get to know why.

However there is a solution to your issue #2-- Observe `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`. It fires any time the overall iCloud state changes-- user logs in, user logs out, user switches accounts.

Comment: I could not get either my iOS app or my tvOS app to receive a `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`. Maybe things have changed over the years (?). However, `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreAccountChange` still works.

Answer (score 0):

```
func isUserSignedIntoICloud() -> Bool {
    return FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken != nil
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.