# Why is iCloud account/CKContainer not being found

Tags: swift, swift3, icloud, cloudkit

Please see my updated question below:

I am working on my first app with CloudKit. I'm trying to test whether a user is connected to iCloud, before looking for transactions.

This is my code (showing various tests):

```
func isICloudContainerAvailable()->Bool {

        CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountStat, error) in
            if (accountStat == .available) {
                print("iCloud is available")
            }
            else {
                print("iCloud is not available")
            }
        }

        CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountStatus, error) in
            switch accountStatus {
            case .available:
                print("iCloud Available")
            case .noAccount:
                print("No iCloud account")
            case .restricted:
                print("iCloud restricted")
            case .couldNotDetermine:
                print("Unable to determine iCloud status")
            }
        }


        if FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken != nil {
            //print("User logged in")
            return true
        }
        else {
            //print("User is not logged in")
            return false
        }
    }
```

This works ok for my own account -- I can work as expected. However, for new users, (ie Apple Review team and my own test users), I get

iCloud Unavailable, and
No iCloud Account

I'm sure that there is an open iCloud account as the new user's iCloud mail is working.

UPDATE

I've had a test user log out and log in again. The first time she starts the app, she gets the noCloud messages. If she restarts the app, it works. I could use some ideas on places to look.. I have confirmed this behavior using my own computer with a new test account.

Comment: What is the value of the ubiquityIdentityToken?

Comment: Hi MirekE, it  is null

Comment: always hit "No iCloud account" condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation,

> *The private database is available only when the value in the ubiquityIdentityToken property is not nil*.

[It also says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW28)

> *There are times when iCloud may not be available to your app, such as when the user disables the Documents & Data feature or signs out of
>   iCloud*.

*Documents and Data* is now apparently what is called *iCloud Drive* in Settings.

So I would ask the users in question if their iCloud Drive setting is enabled and if turning it on makes any difference.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for helping. I'll get back here later. Meanwhile, before other users can use my app, do I need to migrate my container from development to production? Thanks

Comment: If they are testing your app using TestFlight, you need to deploy the database to the production environment. If you have any initial data, I believe you will have to populate them on your own, the deployment process does not copy them.

Comment: I've some progress. The error happens the first time the app is run. If I stop the app, and restart, it works as advertised. Does this ring a bell?

Comment: No, sorry. But if you get `.noAccount`, you should prompt the user to to enable iCloud Drive anyways. And then check for change in credentials using `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` afterwards.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help. I'll leave the question open and see if someone else chimes in.

Comment: Sure, perhaps you could update the original question with latest finding and info whether the users enabled iCloud Drive or not.

Comment: Just to add my experience: on the simulator, the user is logged into iCloud, iCloud Drive is `On`, and the app in question is granted access to iCloud Drive — `FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken` is `nil`. Quite inconvenient.

Comment: With the addition of Mac Catalyst, I had mac users receiving "no account" status for cloudkit. This answer had the crucial clue: "iCloud Drive" setting was disabled on the affected Macs.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not posting this as the correct answer. However, what I learned from an Apple TSI intervention is that this an Apple bug. A suggested workaround -- something I'm still testing is as follows:

```
func isICloudContainerAvailable()->Bool {
        print(#function)
        CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountStatus, error) in

            if accountStatus == .available {
                return
            }

            ///
            // Checking account availability
            // Silently return if everything goes well, or do a second check 200ms after the first failure
            //

            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {

                    guard error != nil, accountStatus != CKAccountStatus.available else {return}

                        print("iCloud account is not available! Be sure you have signed in iCloud on this device!")
                    }
                }


        if FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken != nil {
            //print("User logged in")
            return true
        }
        else {
            //print("User is not logged in")
            return false
        }

    }
```

It essentially does the following..

1. Checks if the container is available.
2. If not, wait 200ms and try once more.

It's a hack, and the 200ms is arbitrary. So far, it seems to work.

Comment: I don't understand this code: The result immediately returned by `isICloudContainerAvailable()` depends only on the test if `ubiquityIdentityToken` is `nil`. The asynchronous check of the account status, which might return a different result, is not used at all, except for a log.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was happening because of disabled `iCloud Drive` in the iCloud settings. Unfortunately there is no way around it and the user will have to enable iCloud Drive otherwise CloudKit's private database won't work at all, and public database will be read-only.

I show a popup message asking the user to log into their iCloud account and make sure their iCloud Drive is enabled otherwise the app won't work.

[image]