# Detect if an iOS user is currently signed into an iCloud account and has 2FA enabled

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, apple-id

How would my app detect if a) the iOS user is signed into an iCloud account AND b) if the 2FA is enabled on that account?

I've been looking at Apple docs like CloudKit, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: the answer to question number one is [found in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335942/check-if-user-is-logged-into-icloud-swift-ios)

Answer (score 0):

**No.**
It's not possible as there is no open API to check about 2-factor auth enable/disable, but yeah feel free to file an enhancement request and describe your use-case so the cloud engineering can think about it.
link for an enhancement request - [click here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)

if it is so important to use the case then navigating users to settings and asking them to enable it, will give u a shot about it, but yeah kinda hack not a solution.

kudos