# How to detect when user disables iCloud per app in settings

Tags: swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm currently observing `.NSUbiquityIdentityDidChange` which I read should be triggered whenever an iCloud related change occurs but it's not being triggered if I disable iCloud for my app in `Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > Apps using iCloud`

[image]

Comment: You could do that using CloudKit API, by checking the account status with one of the options in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335942/check-if-user-is-logged-into-icloud-swift-ios?rq=2

Comment: I need to observe it when it changes.

Comment: Try using `CKAccountChanged` Notification https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1399172-ckaccountchanged

Comment: Thanks, that notification is indeed triggered. Add this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with **CloudKid**.

By registering to [`CKAccountChanged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1399172-ckaccountchanged) Notification.

#### Example

```swift
import CloudKit

...

NotificationCenter
    .default
    .addObserver(forName: .CKAccountChanged, 
                  object: nil, 
                   queue: nil) { notification in

                   }
```