# iCloud is disabled for my iOS app but for share extension iCloud is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I'm testing disabling iCloud for my app (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207689) and it's disabled in my main app but when I use the share extension it's always enabled. I would think that disabling iCloud would disable it for all extensions you might have in your app.

Is there no way to disable iCloud for an extension only for main app?

Comment: I too had noticed odd things happening with app extensions and iCloud. In particular I noticed that app extensions don't receive NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification so disabling iCloud isn't detected. I doubt that the ability to disable extension iCloud access would/could be provided independently to the app.

Comment: Furthermore... the extension can check for iCloud access by consulting `NSFileManager.defaultManager.ubiquityIdentityToken`.

Comment: @MichaelR alright, at the moment I'm doing this in init of my share extension  `container.fetchUserRecordID { id, error in self.userID = id?.recordName }` and if `userID` is not nil then the user is logged in. And it's never nil when I'm in in the share extension for some reason even if I have unchecked iCloud for my app. I Will try to see if the `NSFileManager.defaultManager.ubiquityIdentityToken` yields something else.

Comment: @MichaelR no dice, `NSFileManager.defaultManager.ubiquityIdentityToken` is not nil in share extension even though I've disabled iCloud for my app....

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. You must be using CloudKit not iCloud Drive. The later is detected with `NSFileManager.defaultManager.ubiquityIdentityToken`. So my comments above apply to iCloud Drive not CloudKit.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335942/check-if-user-is-logged-into-icloud-swift-ios

Comment: @MichaelR well my issue is that even though I have disabled iCloud when I'm checking for iCloud access in my share extension it says iCloud is disabled whereas when I'm in my main app it correctly says it's disabled.